# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given in

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am trying to make a simple crawler, to capture individual elements of the page, the crawler itself gives me the information I need, but I would like to write it to an XML file, but the problem is: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given`

Here is my code:

```
...
$data = array(
'img-code' => $element->img,
'ean' => $eant,
'desc' => $description
);
echo $data['img-code'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$eanXML = $doc->createElement('Ean');
$doc->appendChild($data['ean']);

$imgXML = $doc->createElement('Img');
$doc->appendChild($data['img-code']);

$descXML = $doc->createElement('Description');
$doc->appendChild($data['desc']);

echo $doc->saveXML();
....
```

What output I want:

```
<products>
<product>    
    <Ean>My ean number {$data['ean']}</Ean>
    <Img>My IMG {$data['img']}</Img>
    <Description>My Description {$data['desc']}</Description>
</product>
<product>
    <Ean></Ean>
    <Img></Img>
    <Description></Description>
</product>
</products>
```

Comment: what do you think `$eant` is? any wya it should be `$eanXML`

Comment: `$eant` is my EAN code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per the function requirements: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php

you append to a child node, not a string.

```
$eanXML = $doc->createElement('Ean');
$doc->appendChild($eanXML); //append to 'Ean'
```

Comment: Then how i Can put variable to `<Ean>VARIABLE</Ean>` This:
`$eanXML = $doc->createElement('Ean');
 $data['ean'] = $doc->appendChild($eanXML);` 
Not work

Comment: can you give a simple example for your  desired output